# Inline code span inside Markdown table does not render properly

Tags: markdown

How can I add an inline code span element that contains an `|` character inside an inline code span inside a table row. Or in other words how can I make the second row in this table render correctly?

```markdown
| Operator | Description          |
|:---------|:---------------------|
| `&`      | bitwise and operator |
| `|`      | bitwise or operator  | <!-- this doesn't render correctly -->
| `^`      | bitwise xor operator |
| `<<`     | left shift operator  |
| `>>`     | right shift operator |
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this question. There are many flavors of Markdown and even more implementations. Few of them follow a strict specification. On top of that, tables are a syntax *extension* and aren't supported across the board. How the table is *rendered* depends on the actual Markdown *renderer*.

Notably, this works as is here on Stack Overflow.

```markdown
| Operator | Description          |
|:---------|:---------------------|
| `|`      | bitwise or operator  |
```

is rendered as

| Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `|` | bitwise or operator |

To see the result produced by other Markdown renderers, we can use [Babelmark 3](https://babelmark.github.io), a GitHub-hosted tool for comparing the output of various Markdown implementations.

The [output for the table above](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%7C+Operator+%7C+Description++++++++++%7C%0A%7C%3A---------%7C%3A---------------------%7C%0A%7C+%60%7C%60++++++%7C+bitwise+or+operator++%7C%0A) varies. About half the implementations that do support tables render this case correctly, the others don't.

GitHub Flavored Markdown is one example where it fails. The output looks something like this:

| Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ` | ` |

Fortunately, GitHub Flavored Markdown [does have a specification](https://github.github.com/gfm). For the tables extension, it [specifically notes](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-):

> Include a pipe in a cell’s content by escaping it, including inside other inline spans.

So replacing `` `|` `` with `` `\|` `` [fixes the problem](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%7C+Operator+%7C+Description++++++++++%7C%0A%7C%3A---------%7C%3A---------------------%7C%0A%7C+%60%5C%7C%60++++++%7C+bitwise+or+operator++%7C%0A) in this case… but does breaks others.